# Mongo query - Array of Objects - get field from element 0 only

Tags: mongodb

Trying to query Mongo, and get 1 field of element 0, inside a document, namely `emails[0].address`:

Here's a sample (truncated) document structure:

```
    { 
    "_id" : "dfadgfe266reh", 
    "emails" : [
        {
            "address" : "email@domain.com", 
            "verified" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

And my query (truncated) is like this:

```
        {
            fields: {
                'emails.0.address': {
                    address: 1
                }
            }
        }
```

However, when I run this, I get an empty object array, namely `emails:[{}]`
But if I change the selector to `'emails.address'` it will give me the actual email address -- the problem is I only want `emails[0].address`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try db.colname.find( {}, { emails: { $slice: 1 } } )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the required document you need a project document with two attributes. First one, as @Veeram mentioned, [slices](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#project-specific-array-elements-in-the-returned-array) the array and second to specify an attribute from [the embedded document in the array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection-on-embedded-documents-in-an-array). See code:

```
db.collection.find( {}, { "emails": { $slice: 1 } , "emails.address": 1} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#projection) in projection:

```
.find({"emails.address":{$exists:true}}, {"emails.$.address":1})
```